# Georeferencing map with unknown projection and grid

Tags: coordinate-system, proj

It is another question about georeferencing a map with unknown projection and grid.

You can find map [here](https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/Prodesc/proddesc_19532.htm).

As you can see it is already georeferenced, but poorly, I think. Projection used is [ESRI:102115](https://epsg.io/102115), Old Hawaiian UTM Zone 5N. First issue: after I gathered some info, I am not sure Zone 5N could be the right zone for Maui, rather it could be Zone 4N with [ESRI:102115](https://epsg.io/102114). So I tried to georef map with the last one, but still not a great result (error seems comparable).

Then I tried to dig more deep into it and I find some info:

1. Maui belongs to a series of map about Hawaii (Hawaii Division of Hydrography
   Geologic and Topographic Map 1936–1960).
2. As you can see, in Maui there is no info about projection and grid, but I find info about projection and grid used with [Hawaii](https://www.atlasofplaces.com/cartography/geologic-and-topographic-map/#figure-2). **Polyconic projection**, **1928 Hawaiian datum** 5000 yard grid **U.S. zone** system, **central meridian 158°**.
3. Polyconic projection was amply used till 1950s from USGS.
4. [Here](https://evols.library.manoa.hawaii.edu/handle/10524/56950) the projection is mentioned and it is a Polyconic (this time for Maui, not for Hawaii). Same [here](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/510816).

I am using QGIS and I defined a new projection with proj as is:
`+proj=poly +lat_0=20.54167 +lon_0=-156.3375 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=clrk66 +towgs84=61,-285,-181,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`. Then I used it to georef Maui, but still not able to achieve an acceptable result.

So I have three questions:

1. What is the projection used in this map?
2. I also need to know grid used, so I can easily georef it. What is the grid coordinates system?
3. Is Old_Hawaiian_UTM_Zone_5N wrong? Old_Hawaiian_UTM_Zone_4N? I think UTM is new compared to the date of the map (1942). Could be Old Hawaiian / Hawaii zone 2 (EPSG:3562) correct?

Comment: There's degrees marked all over the edges of the map. Use polynominal for georeference-calculations to account for folds visible in the scan and you should be fine.

Comment: Hey @Erik thanks for your comment. When you talk about "polynominal" are you refering to the Type of transformation for georef? If yes, what projection I need to use? I already try different kind of transformation to account distortion or something else, but still I am not able to achieve acceptable result.

Comment: Yes, this is the transformation type. Usually you use Helmert, but for scanned maps polynominal is "safer". How many global CRS utilizing degree are there? Try WGS 84, it should be fitting.

Comment: I am sorry @Erik but I do not get it. When you say "How many global CRS utilizing degree are there" are you refering to how many points I used to georef it? And WGS84 (EPSG: 4326) as CRS for grid or you mean as CRS for georef map (Target SR)?

Comment: Yes, WGS 84  (EPSG 4326) is the CRS you need to use as target CRS. I suggest you set at least seven widely distributed points on the grid-vertices. Nine would be safer though.

Comment: Hi @Erik I tried to follow your suggestion but still I do not get a good result (it seems comparable with other georefs). I used 15 points with Polynomial 1.

Comment: The map sheet tells us base from USGS map survey in 1922-25, so 1928 Hawaiian datum may not be correct.

Comment: Hi @nmtoken, thank to point it out. Do you have some suggestions on what datum or projection can I use?

Comment: Why does it matter what the projection of the original map was in?  You are georeferencing the map - tacking the map down to a known coordinate system.  There are so many latitude and longitude marks that getting the 10+ control points needed for a spline transformation will be easy.  You say the map is poorly georeferenced now.  Is this just because you are comparing a c. 1940 cartographic product with a c. 2020 cartographic product?

Comment: Hi @GBG, it does matter because to many times if I do not use original projection with a scanned map it becomes very skewed (in my limited experience). However does not I need to know original projection also if I want to use georef it with a new one (with QGIS, for example)? I am usually using cartography around 1950s and I get great result also compared to the new one, so my answer is no. I think it is just bad. You can also check it on your own, from website linked in my question. If I missing something, please point it out! Thanks!

Comment: After you georeference the map to your liking you export it to a new file.  It would be this new file that you would use in future GIS projects.